# creating api with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

So I'm new in angular and I'm new with API's
I tried to create thingy, where I can get video information by id, using several tutorials and browsing stackoverflow
I managed to find 2 solutions to the problem, but neither of them work for me.
First I tried

```
mvcApp.service('ApiCall', ['$http', function($http) {
var result;
this.GetApiCall = function() {
    result = $http.get('https://hosting.com/webmasters/video_by_id?id=123456789')
        .success(function(data) {
            result = (data);
        })
        .error(function() {
            alert('Something wrong');
        });
    return result;
}}]);
```

It uses good API link, but return `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` error.

Next solution I found was:

```
mvcApp.factory('json', function($http) {
return {
    getInformation: function (name) {
        var url = 'https://hosting.com/webmasters/video_by_id';
        return $http.jsonp(url, {
            params: {
                id: name
            }
        });
    }
}});
```

This one returns errors, as it does not recognises var as a link, and return `video_by_id?id=123456789:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` error. But as I tinkered with it and looked at some other examples, found out that adding extension to links, fixes this, but I do not have or know an extension. So any help would be valuable

Comment: I dont see _thumbsize_ in your code

Comment: Edited. I removed it, as it was not essential for the problem

Comment: hey, that `:1` is still there on the end for some reason. Where is that coming from, it doesn't look like your hard-coded query? in the sample code you provide... And this time it is on a different parameter.

Comment: Well I dont know it either, it might be app doing it, because it does not recognize it as a link. But as soon as I try to use other API's where link have extensions, for example, if I did video_by_id.php?..... that :1 would dissappear

Comment: And it does not depend on parameter, it ats it to the end

Comment: Check to see if elsewhere in the code there is a call adding an interceptor like $httpProvider.interceptors

Answer (score 0):

If your API is not in the same server as your Angular code, you could [handle CORS on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource), to avoid the error.